# Why do we need state_dict = state_dict.copy()

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

I want to load the weights of a pre-trained model on my local model. I don’t understand why `state_dict = state_dict.copy()` is necessary if the two networks have the same name `state_dict`.

```python
# copy state_dict so _load_from_state_dict can modify it
metadata = getattr(state_dict, '_metadata', None)
state_dict = state_dict.copy()
if metadata is not None:
    state_dict._metadata = metadata

def load(module, prefix=''):

    local_metadata = {} if metadata is None else metadata.get(prefix[:-1], {})
    module._load_from_state_dict(
        state_dict, prefix, local_metadata, True, missing_keys, unexpected_keys, error_msgs)
    for name, child in module._modules.items():
        if child is not None:
            load(child, prefix + name + '.')
start_prefix = ''
# print("hasattr(model, 'bert')",hasattr(model, 'bert')  ) :false
if not hasattr(model, 'bert') and any(s.startswith('bert.') for s in state_dict.keys()):
    start_prefix = 'bert.'
load(model, prefix=start_prefix)
```

Note: the above code is [from Hugging Face](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/38a674599c5b953bd6070e1f42ef3fee59fdb3b7/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L406-L410).

Comment: I would think that this "unlinks" `state_dict` from anything else that might have duplicated that reference, but I'm not sure.

Comment: HTNW is right. if `state_dict` in line 2 refers to the state_dict of another module that you're still using somewhere, `state_dict.copy()` ensures that changes to your new module will not affect the old.

Comment: I am sorry I am not so familiar with PyTorch and didn't get it totally. 
if we have one dictionary named dic1, and we copy another named dic2 like following. then we change the original dic1, dic2 will not be influenced.


    dic1 = {"a":1}
    dic2=dic1.copy()
    dic1["a"]=2


    dic2
{'a': 1}


but here they both name state_dict. how can I know which one is the state_dict of the old module and which one refers to the new one.

Answer (score 4):

```
state_dict = state_dict.copy()
```

does exactly what you tell him to do: it copies in place the state_dict. State dict are all the parameters of your model, and copying it allows to make them independant. One should be careful whether you need a copy or a deepcopy though !